# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 00942. 00000 - "table or view does not exist"

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a small exercise using varray, but I couldn't retrieve the varray table.

```
create type price_array as VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER(6,2)
/

create table price_table(
    pno int,
    prices price_array)
/

insert into price_table values (1,price_array(2.00,3.00,4.00))
/
insert into price_table values (2,price_array(2.00,3.00,4.00))
/
insert into price_table values (3,price_array(2.00,3.00,4.00))
/

select * from PRICE_TABLE
/

SELECT pno, s.COLUMN_VALUE prices
from pricelist p,TABLE(p.prices) s
/
```

Output I got:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 20 Column: 6
```

Comment: What is `pricelist` in that query - is that just supposed to be `price_table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just used the wrong table name; your table is `price_table`, not `pricelist`:

```
SELECT pno, s.COLUMN_VALUE prices
from price_table p,TABLE(p.prices) s
/

       PNO     PRICES
---------- ----------
         1          2
         1          3
         1          4
         2          2
         2          3
         2          4
         3          2
         3          3
         3          4
```